# Power controlling a soldering iron

Tags: power, pwm, soldering

I have used a single rectifying diode to lower power of 60W Chinese soldering iron due to overheating.

Though I am pleased with the result, I still plan to have variable power output for heavy soldering.

This is where I got the idea of PWM.

I am thinking of rectifying the mains with a full wave rectifier as I have found that these soldering irons work with DC as well. Then stepping th mains to 9V for the 555 timer in PWM configuration (the circuit I used is the electronoob's one) feed it to an NPN BJT and use the soldering iron in series with the collector. Additionally I plan to use the 13003/5/7 as the BJT (I also plan to use it in a Darlington pair for higher gain.)

Shall I go for it? Is there any problem with this method?
Also I am compelled to use only 555 as the PWM source.

Comment: draw the circuit you want to ask about

Comment: Depends of voltage, the iron is designed for. For high voltage just from power outlet easiest way to use TRIAC based cheap voltage regulator.

Comment: It should be possible to make this work with those components. Suggest you post your proposed schematic. I would be remiss not to mention that all components will be "hot" in this proposed circuit so everything needs to be properly insulated for safety, including the control pot (ordinary pots often don't have enough insulation to be really safe). As an alternative, consider a cheap triac light dimmer. For 6W, you can get inline dimmers that merely need to be plugged in.

Comment: Using a light dimmer is the easiest way

Comment: Alternatively, instead of buying cheap crap and then try to fix it, you could buy a quality iron, then spend the same amount of time as you would fixing the bad one doing actual work. The salary you earned from doing that actual work can then pay for the quality iron and more.

Comment: You see due to econmic condition and the place I live in I dont have even any access to soldering stations like weller or hakko, etc. These stations are not available nor is it possible to order them online for me. The only thing I can do is look at videos of people using popular brand online while try as much as possible to diy for myself.  But thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I think is to use a light dimmer circuit. You can buy it already assembled (look one for 60 W) and it is plug 'n play. What they do is almost a PWM on the AC signal from the grid using a triac.

If you want to build it yourself, it is very simple, though I see no point on building it other than just for fun:

[image: Triac lamp dimmer circuit]

<sub>Image source: [Circuits Today: Diac Applications, Triac Lamp Dimmer Circuit](https://www.circuitstoday.com/diac-applications)</sub>

Where there is the lamp you should put your soldering gun.

Comment: On the contrary, I see reasons to specifically *not* build it yourself.